# how to check if Google Assistant is available in a device by code?

Tags: android, app-actions

Is Google Assistant available in all Android devices?

Is there any way to check it programmatically?

I need to know if the current device has it available in order to offer some options to the user. As far as I know, at least new **Huawei** Android devices will **not** come with any Google features, right? Neither the Assistant. So is there a way to check that? Maybe a function like this:

```
IsGoogleAssistantAvailable()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use this method to check if app is installed-**

```
private boolean appInstalledOrNot(String uri) {
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        return true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    }

    return false;
}
```

Check like this

For Google Assistant-

```
boolean isAppInstalled = appInstalledOrNot("com.google.android.apps.googleassistant");
```

For Google Assistant Go use this package name - `com.google.android.apps.assistant`

Comment: I'm using a Pixel 3a with a fresh Feb 2020 Android 11 install. As far as I can tell, Google Assistant is installed. When I request the package list via adb, using `pm list packages` I see no packages with the word 'assistant' in the list